# How to add a new chart type dynamically to google candlestick chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

This post show how to add same chart type (line) [How to add another data series to a Google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648255/how-to-add-another-data-series-to-a-google-chart)

and this one is not really candlestick chart [Candlesticks is always on top of lines in combo chart google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696015/candlesticks-is-always-on-top-of-lines-in-combo-chart-google-chart)

True candlestickcharts are not combochart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart

so is it possible to add a line and/or bar chart to a true candlestick google chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `series` option to change the type...

the four candlestick columns will be considered series #: 0

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Candlestick', 'Begin', 'End', 'High'],
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ]);

  // add column for line, add data to rows...
  var colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'Line');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, data.getValue(i, 1));
  }

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```