# Google Charts: Dynamically Add Series to Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

There is a [similar thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648255/how-to-add-another-data-series-to-a-google-chart) but the answer isn't clear and there is no clear example to follow.

I need to dynamically add series to a Google Charts graph. Suppose each successive click of a button should add a new series from my array. Right now it just replaces it. What should I do?

```js
// Init
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

var currentclick = 0;

// My Data
var titles = ['Year1','Year2','Year3','Year4'];
var nums = [ [44,12,33,22], [33,11,7,8], [2,1,65,44] ];

$('#addSeries').click(function() {

   if (currentclick < 3) {
       draw(nums, currentclick);
   }
   currentclick++;
});

function draw(arr, seriesnum) {
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 chartData.addColumn('string', 'Year');
 chartData.addColumn('number', 'Value');  
  
  var chartRowArray = $.makeArray();
 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  chartRowArray.push( [ titles[i], arr[seriesnum][i] ] );
 } 
 chartData.addRows(chartRowArray);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartarea'));
  chart.draw(chartData, null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addSeries">Add Next Series</button>

<div id="chartarea">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is the final structure of the data.

The **Column Array** should be

```
0: Year
1: Value
2: Value
etc.
```

The Column array is added 1-by-1 as `chartData.addColumn(type, name)`.

The data's **Row Array** should be

```
0:  
   0: Year1
   1: 44
   2: 33
1:
   0: Year2
   1: 12
   2: 11
etc.
```

The Row Array is added in one shot as `chartData.addRows(rowArray)`.

Knowing this, I made both **RowArray / ColArray** global variables that get modified on the fly (thanks for the idea *Tainake*) and for the initial conditions when the arrays are empty, I construct or initialize them for the first time.

Working example below. Thanks again for the help!

```js
// Init
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

var currentclick = 0;

// My Data
var titles = ['Year1','Year2','Year3','Year4'];
var nums = [ [44,12,33,22], [33,11,7,8], [2,1,65,44] ];
var chartColArray = $.makeArray(); // Global var
var chartRowArray = $.makeArray(); // Global var

$('#addSeries').click(function() {

   if (currentclick < 3) {
       draw(nums, currentclick);
   }
   currentclick++;
});

function draw(arr, seriesnum) {
 var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 
 // For initial Column, push 'Year'; otherwise, push 'Value'
 if (chartColArray.length == 0) {
  chartColArray.push('Year');
 }
 chartColArray.push('Value');
 // addColumn() has to be 1-by-1-by-1, there is no addColumns(colarray)
 $.each(chartColArray, function(index, item) {
  (index == 0 ? chartData.addColumn('string', item) : chartData.addColumn('number', item));
 });
 
 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // For initial Row subarray, create subarray and push 'Year Series'; 
        // otherwise, push actual 'Series' value
  if (chartRowArray[i] == undefined) {
   chartRowArray[i] = $.makeArray();
   chartRowArray[i].push(titles[seriesnum]);
  }
  chartRowArray[i].push(nums[seriesnum][i]);
 }
 chartData.addRows(chartRowArray);

 // Instantiate and draw the chart.
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartarea'));
 chart.draw(chartData, null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addSeries">Add Next Series</button>

<div id="chartarea">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You want to add a line chart from the data of `nums` every time when you clicked "Add Next Series" button.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, `chartRowArray` is declared as a global variable. When the button is clicked, the data is added to `chartRowArray`. By this, the line chars are added to the existing chart.

#### Modified script:

```js
// Init
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
var currentclick = 0;

// My Data
var titles = ['Year1','Year2','Year3','Year4'];
var nums = [ [44,12,33,22], [33,11,7,8], [2,1,65,44] ];

$('#addSeries').click(function() {
  if (currentclick < 3) {
    draw(nums, currentclick);
  }
  currentclick++;
});

// Below script was modified.
var chartRowArray = $.makeArray(); // Added

function draw(arr, seriesnum) {
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  for (var i = 0; i < seriesnum + 1; i++) { // Added
    chartData.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  }
  if (seriesnum === 0) { // Added
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      chartRowArray.push( [ titles[i], arr[seriesnum][i] ] );
    } 
  } else { // Added
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      chartRowArray[i].push(arr[seriesnum][i]);
    } 
  }
  chartData.addRows(chartRowArray);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartarea'));
  chart.draw(chartData, null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addSeries">Add Next Series</button>
<div id="chartarea"></div>
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of making it a global variable really helped. The example of known NumSeries being known in advance is a bit primitive because I don't know how many series I'll have. Also, I simplified the If-clause to handle the initial condition. I'll post my working simplified version in a moment.

Comment: @gene b. Thank you for replying and additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I upvoted your answer.